# Windows 7 won't stay asleep, how to disable keyboard and mouse?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I have a Razer Deathadder mouse and a stock dell keyboard plugged into my system. When either or both is plugged in, my system wakes up from sleep. A `powercfg -energy` shows roughly 5 devices that are not entering suspend state, and among them is the Deathadder mouse, a "usb input device", and a "usb composite device". What can i do to make my system go to sleep and stay sleeping?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. If the keyboard and mouse are already plugged in does the system wake up, or are they disconnected and then plugged in which wakes the system?

Comment: Only if they're plugged in at the time of sleep does it wake back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't the `-devicedisablewake` option to `powercfg` work?

```
powercfg -devicedisablewake NAME_OF_DEVICE
```

`NAME_OF_DEVICE` is the string you get from `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`. To figure out which device caused the most recent wake-up from sleep state, do

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

Comment: I'll try those just a minute...

Comment: When i try to run a `powercfg -devicedisablewake NAME_OF_DEVICE` (suitably replaced with device name) it tells me i do not have permission to enable or disable device wake even though i'm running as an administrator. Odd...

Comment: I managed to fix it by finding the devices in the Device Manager and turning off their ability to wake from there.