# Windows 7 won't sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting a Windows 7 PC that wouldn't sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/221042/troubleshooting-a-windows-7-pc-that-wouldnt-sleep)

My Windows 7 system resumes from sleep a few seconds after I've asked it to sleep.  I have stopped all the wake devices I can in Device Manager from waking the system.  The system log shows an event that says: Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub.  I cannot prevent the USB Hub devices from waking the computer, there is no such setting in their properties.

Any ideas how to get it to sleep?

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/86875/why-is-windows7-waking-up-after-i-put-it-to-sleep and http://superuser.com/questions/78227/windows-7-wont-stay-asleep-how-to-disable-keyboard-and-mouse may be of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you have some USB device (mouse, keyboard, webcam) that performs a wakeup action. Try to disconnect all USB devices and send the computer to sleep. If that works, you can try to figure out which device causes the problem by having one of them plugged in and sending your system to sleep. (In situations like this the problem is often caused by the mouse or another pointing device.

Comment: A good tool here also is running "powercfg -energy" from an administrative command prompt - if it's a USB problem it may pinpoint it for you on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Shinrai's [link to the network card's power settings](https://superuser.com/questions/86875/why-is-windows7-waking-up-after-i-put-it-to-sleep) worked to solve this.  No idea why it was reporting a USB hub as the cause though!  Shinrai's comments get + votes for this :)

I won't answer my own question, so Michael K's very proper advice gets the vote :)

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it working.